# Android doInBackground and onPostExecute error

Tags: android

I´m trying to populate a listview with a custom adapter. How can I fix the following error:

Type mismatch: cannot convert from JSONObject to JSONArray

I have already changed the params but it didn´t work.

```
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {
   private ProgressDialog pDialog;
   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListResult.this);
       pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
       pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
       pDialog.setCancelable(true);
       pDialog.show();

   }

   @Override
   protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... args) {
       JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

       JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

       return json;  // Type mismatch: cannot convert from JSONObject to JSONArray
   }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray response) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array
                for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){

                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                Medico medico = new Medico();
                medico.setNome(obj.getString("name"));
                medico.setSobrenome(obj.getString("sname"));

                unid = obj.getString("unidade");
                serv = obj.getString("servico");
                esp = obj.getString("espec");

                if(unidade.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(unid) && 
                        servico.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(serv) && 
                        espec.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(esp)){

                    mList.add(medico);

                }                   
                }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

            if(mList.size() > 0){
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }else{
                empty.setText("No results");
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Comment: if the answer below is satisfactory for you, i would be glad if you mark it as such. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are returning as `JSONArray` in `doInBackground`.

Replace the return type as `JSONObject` and handle it accordingly wherever it is used

Answer (score 0):

Your doInBackground is passing an Object ( {} datatype) and your onPostExecute is expecting a Array ( [] datatype). The data type is mismatched. 
Depends on the JSON data you are trying to process, may try change the onPostExecute to accept an JSONObject then access each properties of it:

```js
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObjct response)
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
            try
            {
                // Getting JSON Array
                for (Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : response.entrySet()) 
                {

                }                   
           } catch (JSONException e) 
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

    }
```